# How can I print '--' in the row and column that I want in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I just start learning python for 2 weeks and this is the first time that I use this website.
This is my exercise to practice for today, and I can't solve it. Please help me to solve it.
This is the output that I want.

A)

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 
 2 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 18 

 3 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 27 

 4 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 36 

 5 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 45 

 6 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 54 

 7 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 63 

 8 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 72 

 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

B)

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 
2 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 18 
 
3 --  9 12 15 18 21 -- 27 
 
4 -- 12 -- -- -- 28 -- 36 
 
5 -- 15 -- -- -- 35 -- 45 
 
6 -- 18 -- -- -- 42 -- 54 
 
7 -- 21 28 35 42 49 -- 63 
 
8 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 72 
 
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

And this is my code.

A)

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        if i in range(2, 9):
            if j in range(2, 9):
                print('--', end = ' ')
                continue
        print(f'{i*j:2d}', end = ' ')
    print()
```

B)

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        if i in range(4, 7):
            if j in range(4, 7):
                print('--', end = ' ')
                continue
        print(f'{i*j:2d}', end = ' ')
    print()
```

I want to solve B) and please guide me if there are other way to coding A). Thank you so much.

Comment: Please post your desired output as text, not images of text.

Comment: obligatory: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @Mark This is the exercise from my friend that he give it to me. I learn from my friend who study in computer science. And I study in Environmental Engineering, but now I shouldn't contact him because he need to do his project, so I come to ask in this comunity. I just want to learn about coding to improve my skill for future job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be your updated code:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        if (i in range(4, 7) and j in range(4, 7)) or ((i in (2, 8)  and 2 <= j <=8)  or (2 <= i <= 8 and j in (2,8))):
                print('--', end = ' ')
                continue
        print(f'{i*j:2d}', end = ' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 2 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 18 
 3 --  9 12 15 18 21 -- 27 
 4 -- 12 -- -- -- 28 -- 36 
 5 -- 15 -- -- -- 35 -- 45 
 6 -- 18 -- -- -- 42 -- 54 
 7 -- 21 28 35 42 49 -- 63 
 8 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 72 
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Comment: Wow!. I'm so confused right now. Thank you for helped me.